# Ошибка при сборке проекта на Visual Studio 2012(11) - Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Добрый день! Собираем большой проект на VS2012, который зависит от одной внешней библиотеки .lib. Перед тем, как собрать этот проект, собрали данную библиотеку тоже через VS2012. Далее в большом проекте указали пути для этой библиотеки в компоновщике. В результате, при сборке выскакивает более 300 ошибок вида:
Имя_библиотеки.lib(Имя_obj_файла.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "описание_функции_или_класса".
Пути к данной библиотеке указали в настройках компоновщика и данная библиотека автоматически подхвачена.

Comment: Глупо, но спрошу - у вас не срабатывает разный mangling имен? Т.е. при компиляции библиотеки, например, использованы имена C, а в C++ вы забыли указать для них `extern ЭСЭё,

Comment: Спасибо, решили данную проблему, проблема была в неправильной сборке. А именно сборка была через Cmake, не подтянулись определенные библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в h-файле есть описание функции, а в cpp-файле нет реализации данной функции

Comment: Мы тоже об этом думали, но ведь ошибок более 300 штук, и данные ошибки обращаются к различным функциям, классам и переменным, у которых имеется cpp-реализация. Мы не понимаем, почему компоновщик не видит их вызов через библиотеку, либо надо как вручную пути прописывать?

Comment: Это Ваша библиотека или чья-то?

Comment: Библиотека написана не нами, но мы собрали его из исходного кода, которая была в открытом доступе. Вот пример одной из 300 однотипных ошибок. 1>FesapiCpp.lib(GridConnectionSetRepresentation.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_H5open" –